# How can $\limsup_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ for $f$ discontinuous at $x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My textbook says 
$$\limsup_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \max\{f(x_0), \lim_{h\to 0^+} f( x_0 + h), \lim_{h\to 0^-} f( x_0 + h)\}$$

Assuming $f(x_0)$ is distinct from the latter two values, how can $\limsup f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ equal neither $\limsup f(x)$ approaching $x_0$ from the left or from the right? Doesn't that violate the definition of a limit, since $f(x_0)$ isn't "approached?"

For clarifcation, assuming wlog $f(x_0) < f(x)$, $\sup f(x) = \max\{(f(x_0), f(x))\}$. The limit in question is the value approached as $x$ approaches $x_0$.

Answer: $\limsup f(x)$ has to include $f(x_0)$ in order for the statement "if $\limsup f(x_0) = \liminf f(x_0)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$" to be always true.

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\to x_0}\sup f(x)$ even mean? What is the $\sup$ over if this is a limit?

Comment: Why is this so hard to happen? Imagine f is just constant on a sequence tending to $x_0$, the constant being less than $f(x_0)$ and is equal to the identity function otherwise.

Comment: Please use `\limsup` and even `\limsup\limits_{x\to x_0}`.

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry but your edit is **bad**. More care, please.

Comment: @Did I dont think it is bad, but if you think that my edit is bad then edit yourself according to your criteria

Comment: @Masacroso It is bad, demonstrably so, because $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\sup$ is misleading (see Rushabh's comment for further explanations), thus your appeal to subjectivity is not fitting here. Yes of course, somebody will have to mop the floor after you...

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(1/x) &, x \neq 0 \\ 2 &, x = 0 \end{cases}  \text{.}  $$  What should $\limsup_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ be?

Or to put this another way, why do you think $x_0$ cannot be a point in the sequence implicitly encoded by $x \rightarrow x_0$?  We have to go to some pains to dodge this point in the one-sided limits.  (We don't take sequences of points, we take sequences of offsets, $h$ all required to be of the same sign, hence nonzero.)

Comment: The lim sup on each side is 1, so it would make sense for the "general" lim sup to be the greater of the two, which is 1. My book claims the non-sided lim sup should also take $f(0)$ into account, so instead of 1 it's 2. I don't understand why this is preferred.

Comment: @hiroshin : How do you feel about the sequence of inputs to $f$: $(x_0, x_0, x_0, \dots, x_0, \dots)$?  Is this a sequence we should use in our lim sup?  What value does it put in the set whose supremum we are taking?